# How can I only get the emotion from firebase ML Kit face detection?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

may I know how can I only got the emotion type on the label? And may I know how many emotion type can ML Kit detect?
Here are my code:

```
public void generateLabels(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image_holder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0);
    ImageLabeler laber = ImageLabeling.getClient(ImageLabelerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    laber.process(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<ImageLabel> labels) {
            String labelText = "Result";
            for (ImageLabel label: labels) {
                String text = label.getText();
                float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                labelText += ("\n" + text + ": " + confidence);
            }
            final String finalLabelText = labelText;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(finalLabelText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have some ideas on the label.getText to get all the value from ML Kit, but how can I handle only one type of it?
Since I want to get the emotion type and doing the next.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Your sample code shows usage of the Image Labeling API, but the title refers to Face Detection. The Image Labeling API gives general labels, which might cover some emotion, but it was not designed specifically for that. The Face API does offer a smiling probability, but does not cover other "emotions".

Comment: Did Face API have the following probability sad, angry, scared, disgust?

Comment: No, we never offered that in ML Kit.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider training the emotion classifier for a specific person, you can use the result of MLKit Face Detection and calculate the features like (eye width/height), (eye-cheek distance/height of face) to feed the algorithms like KNN.

And for the future plan of ML Kit SDKs, could you provide the potential use case for the emotion recognition and the potential usage if possible?

Thanks!

Julie from ML Kit